# Dropbox API, OAuth and Apple

Tags: ios, dropbox, appstore-approval

I have created an iOS app that requires a user to link his/her Dropbox account. As part of the initial setup, the user will need to perform an OAuth authentication with Dropbox. Using the latest version of Dropbox API, this OAuth request will result in Dropbox app being fired up or if Dropbox app does not exist on the device, Safari will be fired up instead. Either way, the user will be prompted to enter his/her Dropbox credentials.

In the latter case, there is a link that says "Create account" on Safari. I believe my app was rejected because of this "Create account" link.

> 11.13 Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Has anyone experienced this? Is there any way around it?

As a developer, it is pretty frustrating as this is beyond what I can do. I cannot modify Dropbox's website to remove that link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a version (1.2.2-b2) of the Dropbox iOS SDK that removes both the 'Create Account' and 'Desktop Version' links. It's available in a post by Brian S. at http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=59350

No word yet on if this updated version gets past the approval process or not.

Comment: My app was approved. Sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue. I think the only way that this will work is for dropbox to remove the signup link from the oauth page.

Comment: Have you filed an appeal against this decision?

Comment: It's a client's app, but I think he will. Will let you know if I find anything.